# Бесконечный ViewPager для отображения данных из списка

Tags: java, android

Имеется `List<MyData> dataList`.
В MyData лежат некие данные.

Хочу сделать окно с возможностью перелистывания(вперед\назад) так чтобы первое окно показывало информацию из первого объекта MyData из **dataList**, второе окно второй объект из **dataList**. И не хотелось бы в момент открытии окна активности создавать 50 фрагментов внутри ViewPager для каждого объекта из **dataList**, лучше было бы как то переиспользовать фрагменты внутри ViewPager.

Не подскажите какую нибудь логику решения? Может для этого вовсе не нужен ViewPager...

Comment: Не знаю, что такое `ViewPager`. Но, если это страницы, то почему бы не сделать, что-то типа `list.get(i-1); list.get(i);list.get(i+1);` которые внести в ваш 
 `ViewPager`, чтобы отображать предыдущий, текущий и последующий элементы. Можно как-то это обертунть в метод, который будет брать из листа текущий элемент и на основании брать соседние ( левый и правый). Конечно же, сделайте проверку на их наличие, например, исключите самый левый и правый элементы в случаях `list.get(0)` и `list.get(list.size);` Если я правильно понял задачу

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ViewPager создаёт только на один (в моём эксперементе было 2) элемент на перёд. То есть, если у вас список из 10-ти элементов то будут созданы только два: первый (видимый) и второй (следующий за ним), если вы укажете начать из елемента 1+, то будут созданы три элемента  (как выше и плюс предыдущий). Проблема с которой я столкнулся это если список может превышать 1000 элементов (та даже 100), не хотелось бы в таком случае тянуть это всё из базы сразу и хранить в памяти. Потому я размышляю о применении пагинации для ViewPager, но времени на тот проект не хватает.

По поводу фрагментов стоит задуматься, возможно вам лучше использовать не фрагменты, а например обычный layout и наполнять его через адаптер (всё зависит от вашего типа данных и задач).

И ещё, если вы именно хотите чтобы контейнеры переиспользовались (максимально правильно использовать патерн Holder), то тогда взгляните на [ViewPager2](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/viewpager2) и [тут](https://devcolibri.com/early-introduction-of-viewpager2/), он по сути ничем не отличается от RecyclerView.

На по следок скажу что вы также можете для этой задачи использовать RecyclerView, прецеденты есть, но тут будет немного сложнее.